# how to stop PHP forking a shell_exec?

Tags: php, shell, process, background, apache2

So I am running a lumen application which spins up processes.

these processes are meant to run in the backround and they run as a daemon, we send a start command to the api in php and that spins up the process using shell_exec, this used to be absolutely flawless but something strange has happened in later version of php / apache2 where the process is forked and completely dependent on either apache or php-fpm depending on what mpm module / webserver you're using.

this could be tested quite easily with index.php containing

```
   shell_exec("screen -dmS testing bash -c 'while true; do echo test && sleep 1 ; done'")
```

Then restart php-fpm or apache

is there any way of stopping this behaviour? I have tried > /dev/null etc etc and with & at the end without success, I really need the process to not be dependent on php-fpm or apache2.

Comment: Using a normal shell 'nohup' leaves background tasks running (AFAIK).

Comment: `nohup`, `&` to background, and redirect stdout _and_ stderr to a file or `/dev/null`. But also now the process is truly orphaned and will require someone to log into the server and manually kill it if it misbehaves. Generally forking off background processes like this is a bad idea that will eventually develop any one of a number of issues. I would suggest using a queue [eg: RabbitMQ] to handle submission of async tasks, and a process manager [eg: supervisord] to wrangle the worker processes.